# The "similar question" sections overlaps the footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, asking-questions

When asking a question, the "similar questions" side bar scrolls down, which is cool, but if I go all the way down to the bottom of the page, then the side bar covers up the link to the wiki, the "ubuntu" link, the "programmers" link, and one other link.

[image]

If you guys could fix it so that it does not go down beyond the "post your question" button, that would be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

I partly agree, it is so long that it falls under the footer.

On the other hand, making them relatively short doesn't give enough to people that actually do check it.