# Text from the side overlaps to the footer when I scroll to the bottom most part of the page

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Take a look at this screenshot.

[image]

Then if you scroll at the bottom most part of the page you can see this. I think the text from the side overlaps to the footer of the page.

[image]

It says [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/the-similar-question-sections-overlaps-the-footer) that it is status-complete, but I still see them?

Comment: Please make sure you provide a ***full*** set of information about what browser and operating system you are using.  It may again be a regression of [Bottom bar floating in middle of the page](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/bottom-bar-floating-in-middle-of-the-page)

Comment: Multiple duplicates of this on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel